# How to use the address of the site inside the url tag django

Tags: python, django, paginator

I want to know if it is possible to use such an address??

```
{% url request.get_full_path page %}
```

For example, pages like product list and search are on the same page and have separate links for the paginator

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking. Can provide an example?

Comment: For example, we have the search and store pages, whose functions use the same page
paginator These pages have different addresses
I want to know if there is a way to address the url paginator other than using ifelse?
For example like this?
{% url request.get_full_path page %}